# getParts() get text inputs too

Tags: java, javascript, servlets

I got drag and drop input file field:

```
<div style="margin-bottom: 1em;">
    <div class="file-well">                
        <input type="file" name="file" id="file" multiple/>
        <span id="filewelllabel">Aby dodać CV kliknij tutaj lub przeciągnij i upuść plik w ten obszar.<br/></span>
        <span id="filewelllabel">Możesz dodać jeden plik (.pdf, .doc, .docx, .docm)</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is my servlet upload handle:

```
Collection<Part> fileParts = request.getParts();
String uploadPath= "\\upload\\";

String savedFileName;

for (Part part : fileParts) {
    fileName = getFileName(part);
    savedFileName= temp.getImie() + temp.getNazwisko() + fileName;
    part.write(uploadPath+ File.separator + savedFileName);
}
```

When I add pdf files this is console log:

```
Info:   content-disposition header= form-data; name="imie"
Info:   content-disposition header= form-data; name="nazwisko"
Info:   content-disposition header= form-data; name="telefon"
Info:   content-disposition header= form-data; name="email"
Info:   content-disposition header= form-data; name="uczelnia"
Info:   content-disposition header= form-data; name="doswiadczenie"
Info:   content-disposition header= form-data; name="zainteresowania"
Info:   content-disposition header= form-data; name="czySlyszales"
Info:   content-disposition header= form-data; name="zrodlo"
Info:   content-disposition header= form-data; name="file"; filename="cv — kopia.pdf"
Info:   content-disposition header= form-data; name="file"; filename="cv.pdf"
Info:   content-disposition header= form-data; name="zgoda"
```

and this is result in upload folder
[image]

How can I prevent saving those other files than pdf??
Should it take only file input parts??

Answer (score 2):

Else you could check it like this:

```
if (part.getName().equals("file")) {
```

Now only inputs with name="file" passes the check. It'll return you the same result, but I think it's nicer.

Answer (score 0):

```
 if (fileName != null && !fileName.isEmpty()){
```

or

```
if(part.getContentType() != null){
```

in the servlet file was the solution.